# How can i pass product attribute manufacturer and SKU to javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, product-attribute

I have the following script which i need to add the product brand/manufacturer and SKU

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener('liveload', function() {
        IcecatLive.getDatasheet(
            {           
                'reasonstobuy':'#Container5',
            }, 
            {
            Brand: **$manufacturer**,
            PartCode: **$sku**,
            UserName: 'myusername'
        }, 'en')               
    });
</script>
```

I have added custom.phtml in web/magento/app/design/frontend/MyTemplate/default/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view

which contains

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); 
/* YOU CAN GET ANY PRODUCT ATTRIBUTE HERE. */
echo $_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer') 
echo $_product->getSku(); 
?>
```

I can display the manufacturer and sku in a block on the front end but cant pass the attributes into the above script, how can i pass the php output manufacturer/sku to the javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure this out 30 mins after posting!

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); 
    /* YOU CAN GET ANY PRODUCT ATTRIBUTE HERE. */
    $mpn = $_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer');
    $partcode = $_product->getSku(); 
?>

<script>
    window.addEventListener('liveload', function() {
        IcecatLive.getDatasheet(
            {           
                'reasonstobuy':'#Container5',
            }, 
            {
            Brand:  <?php echo $mpn; ?>;
            PartCode: <?php echo $partcode; ?>;
            UserName: 'myusername'
        }, 'en')               
    });
</script>
```